# find rows where a combination does not exist SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find all rows in a SQL table where a certain combination does not exist. For example, consider the below table.

```
ID  Column_1  Column_2
1.  ID1       ABC
2.  ID1       XYZ
3.  ID1       QWE
4.  ID2       XYZ 
5.  ID2       QWE
6.  ID3       XYZ
7.  ID3       ABC
8.  ID3       QWE
```

In the above table, I need to return ID2 as there's no (ID2,ABC) combination. I am currently doing a WHILE and IF EXISTS for each ID in the table, but, is there a more efficient way? The volume is large here.

**UPDATE:** All of the below answers seem to return the expected values. Does one method have an advantage over others?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: mysql or sql-server .. ???

Comment: sql server. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be you need a not in and subselect

```
 select distinct column_1 
 from my_table 
 where column_1 not in (select column_1 from my_table 
                        where column_2 ='ABC');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need `ID2`, you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select t2.column_1
from t
group by t2.column_1
having count(*) <> (select count(distinct t2.column_2) from t t2);
```

The query is a bit more complicated if you actually want the values that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
with ids (v1) as 
(select distinct v1 from Mytable),
vals (v2) as 
(select distinct v2 from Mytable),
allCombs as
(select v1, v2 from ids, vals)
select * from allCombs c
where not exists (select * from myTable t where c.v1 = t.v1 and c.v2 = t.v2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all all column_1 which don't have one of a list you can do it in the general case like this.

```
-- first make the list
with items_2_find as
(
  SELECT 'ABC' as V
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 'XYZ' as V
    UNION ALL
  SELECT 'QWE' as V
)
-- left join and find missing
SELECT items_2_find.V
FROM items_2_find
LEFT JOIN aTable ON items_2_find.V = aTable.Column_2
WHERE aTable.Column_1 is null
```